# the Console.ReadLine() Doesn't set the string as the user input

Tags: c#

```
public static void GetCommand(string room, string[] items)
{
   Console.WriteLine("what would you like to do?");
   string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine("UserInput1: ", UserInput);
   UserInput = UserInput.ToLower();
   string[] uIn = UserInput.Split();
   Console.WriteLine("UserInput2: ",uIn);
   if (uIn[0] == "get")
   {
       get(room, items, uIn);
       GetCommand(room,items);
   }
   if (uIn[0] == "search")
   {
       search(room, uIn);
   }
   if (uIn[0]== "north" ^ uIn[0] == "south" ^ uIn[0] == "east" ^ uIn[0] == "west")
   {
       Console.WriteLine(":::", uIn[0]);
       move(room, uIn[0]);
   }

   if (uIn[0] == "test")
   {
       test();
   }
   if (uIn[0] == "clear")
   {
       Console.Clear();
   }
}
```

I'm not sure why the UserInput is null and why the seeming simple user input isn't working. I am very new to c# so the code isn't good, sorry in advance.

Comment: Could you post a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example?

Comment: You're not using `Console.WriteLine` correctly.  It should be `Console.WriteLine("UserInput1: {0}", UserInput);`  The `{0}` tells it to insert the first parameter into the format string at that position.  Alternatively you could also do `Console.WriteLine("UserInput1: " + UserInput);` or even `Console.WriteLine($"UserInput1: {UserInput}");`

Comment: Use the debugger; it would have told you `UserInput` was OK.

Comment: Also it's better to use `||` instead of `^` to indicate "OR" instead of "Exclusive OR" as it's more typical and exclusive or isn't really useful since only one of comparisons can ever be true.

Answer (score 2):

Your `UserInput` isn't null it's the printing problem...
When you print you can do it in two ways :

```
Console.WriteLine("UserInput1 : "+UserInput); //use + not ,
```

```
Console.WriteLine("UserInput1 : {0}" , UserInput); //inside the {} u type the position of the parameter {0} is first and {1} is second
```

Note that when you give parameter you use the `,`

The problem you had is that you gave parameter while didn't said to print it (didn't use `{0}`)